# List all groups in multiple Active Directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory

I am trying to connect to 5 AD Domain and list all the group in all the Domain. I am trying to use pyad by running a for loop on domain.

How can I list all the groups in the domain?

Once I have the group details will run the `aduser.ADUser.from_cn()` on each group to get member list

```
import pyad
import pyad.adquery as dqery
from pyad import pyad_setdefaults
from pyad import aduser

pyad_setdefaults(ldap_server="*domain fqdn*", username="***********", password="*************")

dqery.ADQuery(
attributes = ["distinguishedName", "description"],
where_clause = "objectClass = '*'",
base_dn = "DC=*********,DC=*********,DC=********"
)
```

but it ends up with the error

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attributes'

Comment: See [`pyad` documentation](https://zakird.github.io/pyad/pyad.html#searching-active-directory). You are not using `ADQuery` correctly.

Comment: I get error when I do something like below 
```
import pyad.adquery
q = pyad.adquery.ADQuery()

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft OLE DB Service Components', 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

Comment: I tried this too 

```
import pyad.adquery as pp
pp.ADQuery(
attributes = ["distinguishedName", "description"],
where_clause =  "objectClass = '*'",
base_dn = "OU=*******, DC=****, DC=****"
)
```
Error:

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attributes'